# Input parameter $$ .sh script

Tags: bash, input, parameters

I would like to ask that what is the meaning of $$ in a .sh script.
**My program**:

```
#!/bin/sh

V1=$1
V2=$2
V3=$$

echo "$V1 $V2 $V3"
```

**Calling**:
./mypro.sh 1 2 3

**Output**:
1 2 7215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` is the pid of the bash process.

Answer (score 2):

From the bash man page section **Special Parameters**:

> $ Expands  to  the  process  ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.